# Duplicate nodes on XML to dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, xmlreader

I should create a system that reads an XMLSchema and populates a dataset after reading an xml file.
However some xml files have a duplicate field like this:

```
<Data1>
    <Number>20000</Number>
    <Date>2014-08-14</Date>
    <Reference>1</Reference>
    <Reference>3</Reference>
</Data1>
<Data2>
    <Number>30000</Number>
    <Date>2014-09-20</Date>
    <Reference>2</Reference>
</Data2>
```

I would like to make sure that every time there is a   field in the XML file a new row is created in the dataset, with the same fields but the Reference field is different, for example

```
Row 1: Number 20000 | Date: 2014-08-14 | Reference: 1
Row 2: Number 20000 | Date: 2014-08-14 | Reference: 3
Row 3: Number 30000 | Date: 2014-09-20 | Reference: 2
```

I thought about using XMLReader class but i don't know how to work with nodes. 
Sorry for my english, it is not perfect, thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Where is this schema?

Comment: I have to import fields from a generic .xml file to a dataset  whose structure is based on the schema contained in a .xsd file.
The duplicate fields are contained in the .xml file, not in .xsd file

Comment: Can you post the code you use to populate the dataset? I was going to write out some code, but to be honest it would be better for you if we ammend your code. Cheers.

Comment: `I should create a system that reads an XMLSchema...`